# Adding images to GUI in Groovy

Tags: image, user-interface, groovy

Hello I am having trouble adding an image to a GUI label in Groovy. Can anyone help me with the code that would be able to do this? I have searched everywhere and haven't found an answer. I am trying to finish up a project an cannot figure it out.

I am using SwingBuilder to create my GUI
here is what I have tried:

```
// add a text panel
def mainPanel = {
        sB.panel(layout : new BorderLayout(), background: java.awt.Color.LIGHT_GRAY){
            label(text: 'Welcome to your closet', horizontalAlignment: JLabel.CENTER,
                    constraints : BorderLayout.CENTER, icon: ImageIcon('/home/*****/Documents/ComputerScience/CS315/icons/create.png'))
            buttonPanel()
        }
}
```

the error I get is :

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: GUI.ImageIcon() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [/home/*****/Documents/ComputerScience/CS315/icons/create.png]
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: GUI.ImageIcon() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [/home/*****/Documents/ComputerScience/CS315/icons/create.png]
at GUI$_closure11_closure119.doCall(ClosetGUI.groovy:888)
```

using the following fix:

```
label(text: 'Welcome to your closet', horizontalAlignment: JLabel.CENTER,
                    constraints : BorderLayout.CENTER, icon: imageIcon( resource: '/home/*****/Documents/ComputerScience/CS315/icons/create.png'))
            buttonPanel()
```

i get the following error:

```
Caught: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create component for 'imageIcon' reason:     java.lang.RuntimeException: In imageIcon the value argument 'null' does not refer to a file or a class resource
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create component for 'imageIcon' reason:     java.lang.RuntimeException: In imageIcon the value argument 'null' does not refer to a file or a class resource
at GUI$_closure11_closure119.doCall(ClosetGUI.groovy:888)
```

Any help would be amazing
Thank you!

Comment: Can you post some code? Are you using GroovyFX? Swing? SwingBuilder? What have you tried? What's the error you're getting?

Comment: sorry I am using SwingBuilders I will post code now!

Comment: you should be using the lowercase imageIcon, instead of uppercase ImageIcon.

Comment: @ErikPragt I changed it to lowercase and still get a null argument runtime exception. This is why I am so confused because I don't know what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SwingBuilder, loading an image can be done in the following way:

```
imageIcon(resource:'/groovy/ui/ConsoleIcon.png')
```

Or

```
label(icon:imageIcon('http://docs.codehaus.org/download/userResources/GROOVY/logo')
```

This is based on the documentation found [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/SwingBuilder.imageIcon).

I tried the following, and for me, it works:

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;


swing = new SwingBuilder();
gui = swing.frame(title: "Dan's Gui", size: [400, 200], defaultCloseOperation: javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) {

    panel() {
        myLabel = label(text: "")
    }
    panel(layout: new FlowLayout()) {

        button(text: 'next', actionPerformed: { myLabel.setText("bye") })
        button(text: 'previous', actionPerformed: { myLabel.setText("hello") })
        label(icon: imageIcon(new URL('http://jworks.nl/wp-content/jworks/logo.png')))
    }
}

gui.show();
```

Comment: using the second method I still get the error i have posted in my question

Comment: Could you try the updated example? I works for me. What I changed is that I added a 'new URL()' to get the image.

Comment: The updated example works but how could I translate that into using a resource from a saved file? The user will be picking files to show as pictures...